# Ion-items inside ion-tabs disappears

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I have implemented ion-tabs to show my recently viewed products and search results. I am storing the recent items in localstorage and I am binding it in my html. Initially this was working fine, but the list was disappearing frequently. The list was not binding in html. 
I have come across some solutions like - using `$rootScope.apply()`, `$timeout()`, etc.. I have tried everything. Now the number of disappearances has reduced. But still sometimes the list disappears.Unless I reinstall the app, the list is not getting displayed.

In my controller I am doing this :-

```
$scope.$on( "$ionicView.loaded", function( scopes, states ) {
    $scope.init();
});
$timeout(function() {
   $rootScope.$apply(function()
   {
       $rootScope.viewedList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("viewedList") || "[]");
    });
}, 10);
```

The following code is in my html:-

```
  <ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-grey tabs-positive">        
    <ion-tab title="Viewed items">          
       <ion-content class="has-header has-subheader has-tabs-top padding"   style="padding:40px 0" overflow-scroll="true" has-bouncing="false">
          <div ng-repeat="item in viewedList | reverse " >
              <ion-list>
          <ion-item  class="item item-divider" ng-click="productSearch(item.productId)"> 
             <span style="font-weight:bold"> {{item.Description}}</span><br>
                               {{item.productId}}
          </ion-item>     
               </ion-list>
          </div>

          <div ng-if="viewedList.length===0 || viewedList==null">
                <ion-item>No Viewed Items
                </ion-item>
            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Search Results">  
       <!-- Another tab here-->
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Can someone please help me with this issue???

Comment: Can you reproduce in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I can not understand well your problem, such as the list has disappeared just like that?

Comment: @sioesi yes,,, It disappears,, Its like as if it loses the reference of the list,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by using 'track by'

in html I added this :-

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list|reverse track by item.productid">
```

The problem was in our app the list keeps changing and the hash value will also change. And somehow the list loses its reference. Using 'track by' solved this problem.